# Run pytest for Django project on Jenkins

Tags: django, unit-testing, jenkins, pytest

I am trying to run pytest on my Django application via a Jenkins job. But when I run it the following way:

```
cd workspace
pytest
```

I see the following error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I tried exporting it :

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproj.settings
```

And then I see the following error:

> ImportError: No module named myproj.settings

even though my settings file exists in that location. Has anyone tried this before ?

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment that contains your Django module and then do the export and pytest command?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing `pytest-django` in your dependencies.

As for the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` it can be defined within your `pytest.ini`.

https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html#pytest-ini-settings